# Как узнать в Си расширении, сколько всего аргументов передано в Питон функцию, все их просуммировать и вернуть результат?

Tags: python, c, python-c-api

Привет. Самообучаюсь написанию модулей на C для Python по этому адресу https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/arg.html (скоро по работе может пригодиться).

Легко написал пример модуля с функцией `add`, которая суммирует два целых числа.

Как получить количество аргументов, переданных в функцию, чтобы она все их просуммировала и вернула результат? Что и как изменить в коде?

**mymod.c**:

```
#include <Python.h>

static PyObject *
mymod_add(PyObject *self, PyObject *args)
{
    int a = 0, b = 0;
    PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "i|i", &a, &b);
    return Py_BuildValue("i", a + b);
}

static PyMethodDef mymod_methods[] = {
    {"add",  mymod_add, METH_VARARGS, "The method adds two ints."},
    {NULL, NULL, 0, NULL}
};

static struct PyModuleDef mymod_definition = { 
    PyModuleDef_HEAD_INIT,
    "mymod",
    "My test Python module.",
    -1, 
    mymod_methods
};

PyMODINIT_FUNC PyInit_mymod(void)
{
    Py_Initialize();
    return PyModule_Create(&mymod_definition);
}
```

**test.py**:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('.')
import mymod
print(mymod.add(1, 2))
print(mymod.add(1))
```

**Makefile** (на всякий случай):

```
all: mymod.so

mymod.so: mymod.c Makefile
    gcc -shared -fPIC -o mymod.so mymod.c `python3-config --includes --libs --cflags --ldflags`

clean:
    -rm mymod.so
```

Кроме прочего, меня смущает, что когда не передаешь второй аргумент, функция `PyArg_ParseTuple` все равно его поганит непонятно чем, хотя он изначально 0. Как с этим бороться?

Упс, `PyArg_ParseTuple` перестала поганить второй аргумент. Наверное, забыл сделать `make` перед запуском `test.py`. Но это не снимает основного вопроса.

Comment: Ни разу не писал модулей для питона, но смею предположить, что нужно использовать 
https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/tuple.html#c.PyTuple_Size
и 
https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/tuple.html#c.PyTuple_GetItem
Буду рад, если поможет.

Comment: [Обращайте внимание на описания меток](https://i.imgur.com/QwT8TgZ.png).

Comment: @n3r0bi0m4n, добра тебе, `PyTuple_Size` возвращает правильное количество аргументов. Но как по ним потом пройтись циклом и извлечь каждый int из отдельного аргумента?

Comment: @D-side, извиняюсь, просто у вас нет метки `c-extension-api`, которая имеет априори смысл для любого скриптового языка, включая SQL-движки даже.

Comment: @AlexanderZonov по-моему, меток C и Python вполне достаточно. Слабо представляю, что ещё такое сочетание могло бы означать. (Кроме разве что перевода кода между ними, но это оффтопик `:)`) На Мете [смежный вопрос как-то обсуждали](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3113/181100). Если есть желание обсудить, [заглядывайте в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22462/stack-overflow--)!

Comment: @AlexanderZonov, так вторая ссылка в ответе, PyTuple_GetItem, не подходит?

Comment: Если это не в образовательных целях, то Си расширения для Питона удобно в Cython писать. И даже в образовательных, можно посмотреть какой Си код Cython генерирует для: def add(*args):

Comment: `def add(*args, init=0): for s in args: init += s $ return init` (`sum(args, start=init)`)

Comment: @D-side "Слабо представляю, что ещё такое сочетание могло бы означать." — ещё как минимум ctypes, cffi

Comment: @jfs убедительно. Согласен.

Comment: Странное дело, не могу повторить проблему, ваш изначальный код у меня отлично работает.

Comment: Да, и зачем вы инициализируете интерпретатор в `PyInit_mymod`? Ведь здесь нет вызова питоновского кода. Я думаю, `Py_Initialize();` лишнее.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для сравнения, вот C версия, реализующая Питон-функцию:

```py
def add(*args, init=0):
    for s in args:
        init += s
    return init
```

которая пытается ссылки считать (чтобы память не утекала) и не игнорировать возможные ошибки (чтобы исключение получить, а не segfault):

```c
static PyObject* mymod_add(PyObject *self, PyObject *args, PyObject *kwds)
{
  // parse only keyword args
  PyObject *init = NULL;
  static char *kwlist[] = {"init", NULL};

  PyObject *emptytuple = PyTuple_New(0);
  if (emptytuple == NULL)
    return NULL;
  int ret = PyArg_ParseTupleAndKeywords(emptytuple, kwds, "|O", kwlist, &init);
  Py_DECREF(emptytuple);
  if (!ret)
    return NULL;

  if (init == NULL) { // default
    init = PyLong_FromLong(0); // init=0
    if (init == NULL)
      return NULL;
  }
  else {
    Py_INCREF(init); // get ownership
  }

  // sum args
  Py_ssize_t tuplesize = PyTuple_Size(args);
  Py_ssize_t i = 0;
  for ( ; i < tuplesize; ++i) {
    PyObject *item = PyTuple_GetItem(args, i); // borrowed ref
    if (item == NULL) {
      Py_DECREF(init);
      return NULL;
    }

    //NOTE: assume tuple is immutable: no Py_INCREF(item)/Py_DECREF(item)
    PyObject *temp = PyNumber_InPlaceAdd(init, item); // new ref
    Py_DECREF(init);
    if (temp == NULL)
      return NULL;
    init = temp;
  }
  return init;
}

static PyMethodDef module_functions[] = {
  {"add", (PyCFunction)mymod_add, METH_VARARGS | METH_KEYWORDS, "add arguments"},
  {NULL, NULL, 0, NULL}
};
```

Comment: Спасибо. Я  заметил, что если передавать аргументы через `keywords`, то они в `PyTuple_Size` не считаются.

Comment: И по идее контроль над процессом может утечь только через "вызов" макроса, но тогда "API"  работает через либы переключения стека, что вроде как невероятно для скриптового языка общего назначения. Это я к тому, что может быть не надо REFCOUNT так настойчиво считать - зашли в C-функцию - все - ничего не изменится до `return`, либо все совсем по-другому пишется.

Comment: @AlexanderZonov 1-`len(args)` не скажет был ли передан `init` (init только по имени передаётся).  args это кортеж позиционных аргументов. В Питон версии можно init=sentinel использовать, чтобы узнать, что init явно задан (или вообще его убрать). Си код и так всегда знает, так как значение по умолчанию (`PyLong_FromLong(0)`) явно задаётся. 2- *"зашли в С функцию - все - ничего не изменится"* -- в корне не верно. К примеру, PyNumber_InPlaceAdd() это `+=` который в общем случае может произвольный Питон код выполнять. Даже Py_DECREF() может произвольный код вызвать.

Comment: В любом случае неверный refcount к двум вещам ведёт: либо объект раньше времени будет удалён (если incref забыть) пока вы ещё пытаетесь его использовать либо наоборот никогда не будет удалён (если decref забыть): компьютеры имеют конечную память и она закончится рано или поздно.

Answer (score 2):

Что типа этого надо:

```
static PyObject *
mymod_add(PyObject *self, PyObject *args) {
    double sum = 0;
    PyObject *iterator = PyObject_GetIter(args);
    if (iterator == NULL)
        return -1;

    while (true) {
        PyObject* value = PyIter_Next(iterator);
        if (value == NULL)
            break;
        sum += PyLong_AsDouble(value);
        Py_DECREF(value);
    }
    Py_DECREF(iterator);
    return PyLong_FromDouble(sum);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

[Вариант с итератором](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/715967), конечно, интереснее. Но приведу и свой код.

```
#include <stdio.h>

static PyObject *
mymod_add(PyObject *self, PyObject *args)
{
    PyObject *item;
    int size;
    long sum = 0;

    size = PyTuple_Size(args);
    fprintf(stdout, "Arguments count: %d\n", size);

    for(int i=0; i < size; i++) {
        if(PyLong_Check(item = PyTuple_GetItem(args, i)))
            sum += PyLong_AsLong(item);
        else
            fprintf(stderr, "Failed arg № %d\n", i);
    }
    return Py_BuildValue("l", sum);
}
```

Comment: стоит overflow проверять и другие ошибки. К примеру, посмотрите [как встроенная `sum()` функция числа в диапазоне long складывает](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/e3b2b4b8d9e751b49e3550cb83ba39b54fdc377c/Python/bltinmodule.c#L2267-L2273)