# Объявить метод класса в c-python API

Tags: python, c, классы, python-c-api

Добрый день!

Я по вот этому https://docs.python.org/2/extending/newtypes.html туториалу в самых общих чертах разобрался, как объявлять классы для Python в С.

К сожалению не могу понять как объявить метод класса - чуть более сложный, чем в туториале. А именно - такой, который возьмет на вход произвольный PyObject и вернет его же. Если есть специалисты по данной теме, дайте пожалуйста сниппет кода. Спасибо.

Comment: по ссылке явно показано, как метод объявить ([`Noddy_name`](https://docs.python.org/3/extending/newtypes.html#adding-data-and-methods-to-the-basic-example)). Аргументы можно передавать как и в любую другую функцию, [пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/716432/23044)

Answer (score 0):

Все решилось. При регистрации метода в

static PyMethodDef Noddy_methods[] = {
    {"name", (PyCFunction)Noddy_name, METH_NOARGS,...

надо указать METH_VARARGS и дальше работать с ними как указано здесь https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/structures.html#METH_VARARGS

Но вообще по исходному туториалу/докфайлу это понять довольно проблематично к сожалению.

Comment: `METH_VARARGS` это всего один из нескольких вариантов. Я выше [ссылку привёл на пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/716432/23044), который `METH_KEYWORDS` использует. От потребностей зависит, что выбрать. Чтобы найти документацию, я просто представляю как желаемая страница могла бы выглядеть (ту часть которую знаю)  и поисковику соответствующие слова скармливаю. [Документация достаточно подробно](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/structures.html#c.PyMethodDef) все флаги описывает.