# Запустить Python класс из кода C++

Tags: c++, python, linux, boost, python-c-api

Допустим, что объявлен простой класс на языке Python в файле example.py:

```py
class point:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def print_position(self):
        return "X: {0} Y: {1}\n".format(self.x, self.y)
```

Как вызвать метод `print_position` из кода написанного на `C++`?

main.cpp:

```cpp
#include<python2.7/Python.h>
#include <boost/python.hpp>

int main()
{
     Py_Initialize();
     // ... CODE HERE
     Py_Finalize();
}
```

Смотрел в сторону Cyhton и Boost/Python, но точно разобраться не получилось.
Ссылки в которых что-то нашел:

- [Первая ссылка](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37577676/using-python-objects-in-c)
- [Вторая ссылка](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5055443/boost-python-how-to-pass-a-c-class-instance-to-a-python-class)

Comment: связанный вопрос [Как с помощью python сделать модуль для c++](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/726439/23044)

Comment: @jfs как я понял, тут возможно создать `std::string` в которую передать все необходимые для исполнения в `python` команды и потом просто выполнить ее используя `PyRun_SimpleString( command for execution)`, но такое решение не хотелось бы использовать. В идеале хотелось бы такую схему: в `C++` файле объявлен `std::vector<int> a = {1,2,3}`, после этого создать объект класса который объявлен в `python` модуле и который выполняет кучу сложных манипуляций с данным вектором, выполнить их и вернуть результат все в том-же `C++` модуле.

Comment: вы определитесь что вы хотите: расширить Питон или встроить Питон (противоположные вещи); вызвать код, который объект из Питон-класса создаёт или наоборот из Питона вызывать C++ код, который C++ классы может использовать или вы хотите обернуть C++ класс и предоставить интерфейс для Питона. Можно и [встраивать и расширять Питон одновременно если необходимо](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12098423/4279)

Comment: @jfs я хочу встроить `python` в  код `C++`. Хочу внутри `C++` кода создать объект класса, который объявлен в `python` модуле, выполнить над этим объектом некотрые методы этого класса, объявленные в том-же модуле `python` и получить результат. (Все это внутри  `C++` кода)

Comment: @jfs, в Вашем [примере](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12083562/boostpython-and-functions-with-variables/12098423#12098423) создается расширение для `python`  которое потом используется в `PyRun_SimpleString( command for execution)`. Я не увидел в нем возможности создать внутри `C++` файла объект класса объявленного в `python` модуле.

Comment: с точки зрения C++, все Питон объекты это указатели на PyObject. Вы можете импортировать модуль, получить класс, в нём определённый, вызывать этот класс, чтобы объект получить, получить атрибуты этого объекта (к примеру метод какой-нибудь), вызвать этот метод—[через Python C API это будет крайне многословно](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/716432/23044), проще на Питоне писать: `import module; module.Klass(1).method("a", 2)`. Обычно лучше расширить Питон, чем встраивать (если только вы не для других возможности скриптования создаёте как в Blender, Maya, Open Office).

Comment: @jfs, спасибо за ответ, если был бы пример кода этой многословности было-бы замечательно :) Я хотел-бы встроить `python` в `C++` код, так как у меня в одном из классов `C++` есть скрытое поле матрица. А над этой матрицей мне необходимо выполнить некотрые операции из `python`. Поэтому я хотел вынуть матрицу из класса используя `getter()` внутри `C++`, передать ее как аргумент классу созданному в `python` модуле и импортированному в код `C++`, с помощью методов класса описанного в `python` модуле получить результат этих манипуляций, и дальше что-то с ним сделать внутри все той-же `C++` части.

Comment: пример многословности C API по ссылке. Отдельные шаги явно приведены (можно по каждому отдельный SO вопрос задать: "как импортировать модуль, используя C API").¶ Хотя это выглядит как XY-задача. Начните с  маленьких рабочих примеров чтобы освоиться. Ещё раз повторюсь: рассмотрите вариант с расширением Питона: использовать его как клей, который компоненты (и на других языках) вместе собирает.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

При ответе на вопрос очень помогли ответы выше и ответы [по ссылке](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39813301/creating-a-python-object-in-c-and-calling-its-method).

Структура проекта следующая: в одной папке лежат файлы main.cpp и example.py.

Файл example.py:

```py
class point:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def print_position(self):
        return "X: {0} Y: {1}\n".format(self.x, self.y)
```

Файл main.cpp:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <python2.7/Python.h>
//#include <boost/python.hpp>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    Py_Initialize();

    // Для импорта созданного мною модуля необходимо передать 
    // его имя как аргумент командной строки (у меня example.py)
    PySys_SetArgv(argc, argv);
    PyObject* module_name = PyString_FromString("example");

    // Загрузка модуля (example.py)
    PyObject* module = PyImport_Import(module_name);
    if (module == nullptr)
    {
        PyErr_Print();
        std::cerr << "Failed to import module\n";
        return 1;
    }

    // Загрузка пространств имен модуля
    PyObject* dict = PyModule_GetDict(module);
    if (dict == nullptr)
    {
        PyErr_Print();
        std::cerr << "Failed to import __dict__\n";
        return 1;
    }

    // Загрузка класса из example.py
    std::string py_class_name = "point";
    PyObject* py_class = PyDict_GetItemString(dict, py_class_name.c_str());
    if(py_class == nullptr)
    {
        PyErr_Print();
        std::cerr << "Failed import class " << py_class_name << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    // Поскольку конструктор принимает пару аргументов
    // То необходимо создать пару аргументов
    PyObject* py_arg_tuple = PyTuple_New(2);
    PyTuple_SetItem(py_arg_tuple, 0, PyInt_FromLong(5));
    PyTuple_SetItem(py_arg_tuple, 1, PyInt_FromLong(10));

    // Создание объекта класса point
    PyObject* obj;
    if (PyCallable_Check(py_class))
        obj = PyObject_CallObject(py_class, py_arg_tuple);
    else
        std::cout << "Cannot instantiate the Python class" << std::endl;

    // Вызываем метод print_position класса point
    PyObject* val = PyObject_CallMethod(obj, "print_position", NULL);
    if (!val)
        PyErr_Print();

    // конвертируем результат в std::string и печатаем
    std::string s (PyString_AsString(val));
    std::cout << s;

    Py_Finalize();

    return 0;
}
```

Для запуска под Ubuntu в консоли необходимо ввести команды:

```sh
$ g++ main.cpp -std=c++11 -lpython2.7
$ ./a.out example
```

P.S. аргумент командной строки совпадает с названием импортируемого и написанного мною Python модуля.

Answer (score 4):

[Отсюда](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11805/Embedding-Python-in-C-C-Part-I) (с небольшими правками под Python 3.5 и дополнительными проверками)

```
#include <Python.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    PyObject *pName, *pModule, *pDict, *pClass, *pInstance, *pValue;
    int i, arg[8];

    if (argc < 4) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: call module_name class_name method_name [arguments]\n");
        return 1;
    }

    Py_Initialize();

    // Преобразуем первый аргумент в unicode-строку python    
    pName = PyUnicode_DecodeFSDefault(argv[1]);
    // Импортируем модуль
    // import module_name
    pModule = PyImport_Import(pName);
    Py_DECREF(pName);   // Освобождаем ссылку на строку с именем модуля

    if (pModule != NULL) {
        // Получаем пространство имён (__dict__) модуля
        pDict = PyModule_GetDict(pModule);

        // Получаем класс class_name
        pClass = PyDict_GetItemString(pDict, argv[2]);

        // Проверяем, что полученный class_name можно вызвать
        if (pClass && PyCallable_Check(pClass)) {
            // Получаем объект
            // obj = class_name()
            pInstance = PyObject_CallObject(pClass, NULL); 

            if(pInstance != NULL) {
                // Подготавливаем параметры
                if(argc > 4) {
                    for (i = 0; i < argc - 4; i++) {
                        arg[i] = atoi(argv[i + 4]);
                    }
                    // Вызываем метод с двумя параметрами
                    // value = obj.multiply2(3, 2)
                    pValue = PyObject_CallMethod(pInstance, argv[3], "(ii)", arg[0], arg[1]);

                } 
                else {
                    // Вызываем метод без параметров
                    // value = obj.multiply()
                    pValue = PyObject_CallMethod(pInstance, argv[3], NULL);
                }

                if (pValue != NULL) {
                    printf("Return of call : %d\n", PyLong_AsLong(pValue));
                    // Освобождаем ссылку на выделенную в памяти
                    // переменную для возвращённого из метода результата
                    Py_DECREF(pValue);
                }
                else {
                    PyErr_Print();
                }

                Py_DECREF(pInstance); // Освобождаем ссылку на объект
            }
            else {
                PyErr_Print();
            }

            Py_DECREF(pClass); // Освобождаем ссылку на класс
        }
        else {
            if (PyErr_Occurred())
                PyErr_Print();
            fprintf(stderr, "Cannot find class \"%s\"\n", argv[2]);        
        }

        Py_DECREF(pDict); // Освобождаем ссылку на пространство имён
        Py_DECREF(pModule); // Освобождаем ссылку на модуль
    }
    else {
        PyErr_Print();
    }

    Py_Finalize();

    return 0;
}
```

Как заметил @jfs, это только пример, код сильно упрощён для ясности. В боевом проекте на те же операции будет раза в два больше кода. Или в четыре, если понадобится многопоточность.

Comment: для ясности можно упомянуть, что это выполняет: `import module_name; module_name.class_name().method_name(*args)`, что многословность Си кода демонстрирует, не смотря на отсутствие обработки ошибок, обработки GIL, других полезных вещей.

Comment: @jfs обильно прокомментировал код.

Comment: @jfs спасибо за коментарии они очень помогли разобраться.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev большое спасибо за ответ - он помог разобраться.