# Запустить python-файл из кода cpp-файла, при этом передать аргументы и выполнить только определенные функции в py-файле

Tags: c++, python

Например есть

```
def doSome(arg):
  #Что нибудь
  return something

def doDo(arg1,arg2):
  #Что нибудь
  return something
```

Например, запустил этот файл, передав ему аргумент. Если передал такой то аргумент 1, то выполнить `doDo`, если другой аргумент, то `doSome`

Как можно запустить этот py-файл в коде cpp-файла (то есть использовать C++), выполнить только одну из двух функции и получить возвращаемое значение? Например py-файл возвращает после выполнения функции `doDo` и `doSome` массив, запустив из cpp-файла, я бы хотел выполнить только `doDo` и получить массив. Есть ли для питона что-то типа `int main(int arg, char **argv)`?

Comment: А есть возможность разбросать эти функции по разным файлам? Тогда проще будет. Передача параметров командной строки в питоне, конечно же, есть.

Comment: Да, конечно. А как передавать параметры для скрипта из кода cpp-файла?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/extending/embedding.html

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Запустить Python класс из кода C++](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/785574/204271)

Comment: Boost python в помощь. Но учтите, что из-за GIL у интерпретатора питона проблемы с распараллеливание. Так что будьте осторожны если используете потоки